# bialgebras on quotient polynomials

Tags: hopf-algebras, coalgebras

Is there a general procedure for constructing a bi-algebra out of a quotient polynomial ring? In particular, how do I construct a bi-algebra corresponding to quotient polynomial ring $<x^2-x-1>$? What would be the co-multiplication and co-unit?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

There is no general procedure. if you have a commutative ring, then if for example it is also a reducible ring, we can write $A = K[X]$ for some algebraic variety $X$, and then giving a bialgebra structure on it is the same thing as to give a monoid structure on $X$: there are many ways to do so. 
By the way, if you have nilpotent elements in your ring, a theorem of Waterhouse shows for example that it cannot be a Hopf algebra (it can be a bialgebra still, see for example $K[x]/(x^n-x^{n-1})$ with $\Delta(x) = x\otimes x$).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It would be very helpful if you could explain how I can make a bi-algebra on $K(x)/(x^2-x-1)$ for example? In particular, what should be the comultiplication and counit?

Comment: Assuming that the characteristic of the field is not 2, this algebra is isomorphic with $K\oplus K$. Now think of this as the function algebra on the group of order 2. This will give you all the maps: the comultiplication will be induced by the multiplication in the group, the counit is given by evaluation on the unit element of the group, and in this case the antipode will be the identity.

Comment: @EhudMeir could you please provide a reference for the Waterhouse theorem?

Comment: @PabloS.Ocal The theorem appears in this book:
https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-6217-6
I believe it is in Section 11.4. Notice that this only holds for characteristic zero, I should have written this in the original post.